# Apply separate theme to multiple store view in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, multistore, websites

I created multiple store views in the backend like Store 1, Store 2, and Store 3. Now I have three separate themes so want to assign them separately to store views.

In the backend System-> Configuration, I assigned the store view to the new theme but it always shows an old theme in the view source.

Can you please help me with how can I assign a separate theme to multiple store views in Magento 2?

Comment: There's nothing like System -> Configuration. What have you done exactly after, supposedly, setting your theme under Content -> Configuration? Cleared the caches?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner yes I cleared cache. remove pub/static/* once. Actually, I have one theme Vendor/Theme and this is assigned to three store views. Now I want to add separate CSS for each store so I tried to create another theme VendorStore/Themestore but it is still showing a theme Vendor/Theme in the store view on the frontend.

Comment: Difficult/impossible to say without knowing anything about your child themes

Comment: I created the VendorStore/ThemeStore theme of the Magento/Luma theme.

Comment: Please help me in such situation of how can I assign the separate CSS to three store view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup different theme for different stores. You need to go:

```
Content -> Configuration
```

Here you will find different stores. Edit each store and choose theme. You have installed.